# I lost my taskbars (?) on my Chromebook running Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xfce, chromebook

First off, this is my first foray into the world of Linux and I'm liking it so far. I followed [this guide](https://www.codedonut.com/chromebook/install-crouton-chromebook/) (which was very good) and got Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Xfce to work very well.

However I've run into a bit of an annoying issue. I've somehow lost the taskbar that was at the top of the screen and the icons at the bottom. I don't really know what the correct names of those are but I'd very much like to get them back.

[image]

I don't know what I did to lose them, but I lost them upon the first restart I did to see if I could get back into Ubuntu, which I was able to. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute the command `xfce4-panel` automatically everytime you boot you must:

Open **Session and Startup** from the XFCE menu or type into a terminal:

Press **Ctrl+Alt+T** and type:

```
xfce4-session-settings
```

Click on Tab **Application Autostart**

Click on **+Add**

**Name:** *Anything you like*

**Description:** *Anything you like*

**Command:** **xfce4-panel**

Click **OK**

Make sure is listed in the menu and also the **check box must be ticked**.

Do a reboot to check

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Thanks again for another useful tip, I didn't know that the problem was it wasn't launching the panel on boot. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Press **Ctrl+Alt+T** to open a terminal:

Type:

```
xfce4-panel
```

**OR**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
sudo shutdown -r now
```

---

**IF you can't access to a terminal use the shell:**

Press **Ctrl+Alt+F1**

Type your username and password

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The first command worked a charm. I'll favorite this so I don't forget it.